# Django - markup parser in template or view?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a website where my pages are written in MediaWiki Markup, for which I have a working parser function in Python.

Where exactly do I parse my markup: in the view's code, or in the template? My first guess would be something like:

```
return render_to_response( 'blog/post.html', {'post': post,
                           'content': parseMyMarkup(post.content) })
```

Is this the usual convention, or should I do something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule for deciding whether or not to place your code in the view or the template is this:

> If your code is going to modify the
>   data, put it into the view. If your
>   code will only effect the display of
>   the data, put it into the template.

I'm not very familiar with the markup formatting, but if you are going to be performing substitution (eg: `**word** becomes <b>word</b>`), then I'd put it into the view as it will be modifying your data.

Hope that helps!